# Is there a way to delete option after click in react-simple-chatbot?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, bots, chat

I have a react.js component:

```
import ChatBot from 'react-simple-chatbot';

<ChatBot
  steps={[
      {
        id: '1',
        message: 'What number I am thinking?',
        trigger: '2',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        options: [
          { value: 1, label: 'Number 1', trigger: '4' },
          { value: 2, label: 'Number 2', trigger: '3' },
          { value: 3, label: 'Number 3', trigger: '3' },
          { value: 4, label: 'Number 3', trigger: '3' },
          { value: 5, label: 'Number 3', trigger: '3' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        message: 'Wrong answer, try again.',
        trigger: '2',
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        message: 'Awesome! You are a telepath!',
        end: true,
      },
    ]}
/>
```

After clicking on one of the options, i would like it not to be displayed again in the next step. I tried almost everything like state, filter() and lot of more to do that, and nothing works :'(.

ChatBot **Documentation**: https://lucasbassetti.com.br/react-simple-chatbot/#/docs/options

Please help :[